# CPU usage is increased gradually until the computer is suspended, although doing nothing

Tags: suspend, cpu

I’ve installed both of Ubuntu (14.04 LTS) and Windows on my computer. After a long time not using Ubuntu, I’ve decided to erase disk and install Ubuntu (v16.04 LTS). However, after it has been installed successfully, I’ve encountered the problem that the CPU usage has been increased constantly. Then my computer has been suspended after few minutes because of overloading. You must notice that the OS was original, I haven’t installed any programs or done anything after turning on the computer.  I’ve just opened System Monitor to check system’s statistics.

I don’t know why but I had used Ubuntu normally before. This only happen when I reinstall the OS,  I try to reinstall Ubuntu 14.04 or other ones like version 15 and use the function “Try Ubuntu without installing” but nothing changes, the problem has still remained.

The image below shows information about CPU history right after logging in my computer

And after few minutes, it increases considerably

[image]

Here are the statistics in the Terminal

[image]

Comment: After its been on for a few minutes, in the `terminal`, type `top` and see what process is at the top of the list, and note how much CPU percentage it's using. Copy/paste that screen into your question.

Comment: @heynnema I just only post 2 image links, so I've removed the first image and added the image of the Terminal.

Comment: The `top` command shows that it was trying to do a Software Update, and because of that, or something else, the `kidle_inject` processes were trying to cool down the machine. Is this a laptop or desktop machine? How old? Have you ever run the `Software Updater` and let it complete any updates? Do you hear cooling fans running on the machine?

Comment: - My laptop is 4 years old. But I brought it to the store to clean it early last year.
- Yes, I can hear that the fan is still running
- No, I haven't update anything yet. As I mentioned before, this problem happened even when I tried ubuntu without installing

Comment: Do the Software Updates. Reboot. Let it run for a little while. Then do the `top` command again. Ping me at `@heynnema` when you have new results.